# Pagination with union and two subquery

Tags: mysql

I need some tip for make a query for retrive 5 featured products in every page (I need render eleven per page, 5 are featured  products and 6 normal), I have tried with an union but when I change the outer limit to LIMIT 5 OFFSET 5 (page 2), theres not featured products showed, is something than am I missing?

I have tried this query:

```
SELECT * FROM ( 
              (SELECT a.id, concat(city.description, '-', department.description) as location, a.featured, a.price, a.title, a.description   FROM ads a
              LEFT JOIN city on a.city_id =  city.id
              LEFT JOIN department on city.department_id = department.id
              WHERE featured = true  order by a.price limit 5 offset 0)
              union all        
              SELECT a.id, concat(city.description, '-', department.description) as location, a.featured, a.price, a.title, a.description FROM ads a
              LEFT JOIN city on a.city_id =  city.id
              LEFT JOIN department on city.department_id = department.id
              WHERE featured = false
 ) as a            
 ORDER BY featured desc LIMIT 11 OFFSET 0
```

I expect the output with the next featured and normal products, but only getting normals for a total of 6 records

Comment: limit / offset aren't deterministic without and `ORDER BY`

Comment: @danblack you right, I have edited the query, but the result is the same

Comment: Do you want to see 5 records per page, or 6 records per page or 11 records per page?

Comment: hi @zedfoxus, I need always 5 featured per page but 6 normal products per page, for 11 in total

Comment: Do you want those 11 products sorted so that the 5 featured products appear at the top of the records or bottom of the records?

Comment: Yes, I want the 5 featured products appear in every page at first place

Comment: @zedfoxus hi,  5 featured products at the top in every page, thanks for asking

Comment: @EduarDev just added an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. This will combine your 5 featured and 6 not-featured products and set priority to the featured, and order it by featured first. Your application can take the first 5 results and show it on the top of every page.

```
select * from (
    SELECT 1 as priority, a.id, concat(city.description, '-', department.description) as location, a.featured, a.price, a.title, a.description
    FROM ads a
    LEFT JOIN city on a.city_id =  city.id
    LEFT JOIN department on city.department_id = department.id
    WHERE featured = true
    ORDER BY a.price
    LIMIT 5 offset 0
) x
union all
select * from (
    SELECT 2 as priority, a.id, concat(city.description, '-', department.description) as location, a.featured, a.price, a.title, a.description
    FROM ads a
    LEFT JOIN city on a.city_id =  city.id
    LEFT JOIN department on city.department_id = department.id
    WHERE featured = false
    ORDER BY a.price
    LIMIT 6 offset 0
) y
order by priority
```

There's yet another way you should try this. If you want featured products on every page, it'd be best if you query 5 featured items separately and store the information in a session. That way, when a user goes from page to page, you don't have to re-query those featured items. You can just pull that information from the user's session. Non-featured products can be queried separately.

## If you have fewer featured products and want to substitute featured products

If you have fewer than 5 featured items, you should keep a track of that in a variable. Then, run:

```
select * from (
    SELECT 1 as priority, a.id, concat(city.description, '-', department.description) as location, a.featured, a.price, a.title, a.description
    FROM ads a
    LEFT JOIN city on a.city_id =  city.id
    LEFT JOIN department on city.department_id = department.id
    WHERE featured = false
    ORDER BY a.price
    LIMIT 5 - <ENTER-YOUR-VARIABLE-HERE> offset 0
) y
```

Combine the featured products with the substituted non-featured products to get 5 items.

Then run the last query to pull 6 non-featured products:

```
select * from (
    SELECT 2 as priority, a.id, concat(city.description, '-', department.description) as location, a.featured, a.price, a.title, a.description
    FROM ads a
    LEFT JOIN city on a.city_id =  city.id
    LEFT JOIN department on city.department_id = department.id
    WHERE featured = false
    ORDER BY a.price
    LIMIT 6 offset 0
) y
```

## If you have fewer featured products and DON'T want to substitute featured products

If you have fewer than 5 featured items (say, just 3) you should keep a track of that in a variable. Then, run:

```
select * from (
    SELECT 2 as priority, a.id, concat(city.description, '-', department.description) as location, a.featured, a.price, a.title, a.description
    FROM ads a
    LEFT JOIN city on a.city_id =  city.id
    LEFT JOIN department on city.department_id = department.id
    WHERE featured = false
    ORDER BY a.price
    LIMIT 11 - <ENTER-YOUR-VARIABLE-HERE> offset 0
) y
```

Comment: Hi, thanks very much for you help, here is something else taking your example, if there's not enough featured products, how I can fill the result with normals, I mean if only get 3 featured then I need 8 normal for fill the 11 records, do you have some advice? thanks

Comment: @EduarDev added recommendation on how you would fill 11 records

Comment: It's been my pleasure @EduarDev.